# Two Body Tags? Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

I don't have 2 body tags yet Notepad++ is saying this...

> Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.

From line 7, column 1; to line 7, column 6

```
</header>↩<body>↩<nav>
```

Comment: Is that your whole file (I guess not because it says line 7)? Can you please show your whole file?

Answer (score 2):

Your `<body>` tag is on a line following a `</header>` end tag. A `<header>` element is a semantic header that belongs in the page body. It is not the same thing as the page `<head>`. Because there is a `<header>` element in that position the validator is considered to be in the "in body" insertion state already, since a `<header>` can only appear within the page body. So the validator doesn't expect to see a `<body>` start tag there.

You probably meant `</head>`, not `</header>`. Or if you actually do have a header element there, you need to move it into the body.